# Laravel's functional testing JSON API fails with an error when attaching files

Tags: php, phpunit, functional-testing, laravel-5

So I've written a functional test for testing an upload feature but it fails with the following error:

```
1) UploadTest::testValidVideoUpload
Error: Call to a member function filter() on null

/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:765
/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:737
/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:718
/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:639
/.../tests/ShareTests/UploadTest.php:19
```

And the code is:

```
public function testValidVideoUpload()
{
    $this->post(route('share.upload'), ['type' => 'video'])
        ->attach($this->test_case_files_path . 'testcase.mp4', 'file')
        ->seeJson(['error' => false]);
}
```

I'm using:

- Laravel 5.2 Stable
- phpUnit 5.2.2
- PHP 7.0.3-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )

### EDIT:

I'm using these tests on a RESTful service. Can we use the `attach` method for that??? Because I looked at its implementation and it uses DOM parsers and CSS selectors to find out if that input name actually exists in a reponse!!!!

Comment: What's the content of the method you're testing?

Comment: If I use a REST client, the upload will succeed. So I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie there. So I'm almost sure it wouldn't help you. Do you think it would?

Comment: It helps to be able to see the subject code is all

Comment: @Jakub Zalas: I'm new to unit testing, but I'm pretty certain I'm talking about unit testing :|. Each `test` tests a route, which is handled by a single method, hence the name: UNIT testing. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're wrong :) A unit test is a test for a smallest testable part of an application. In OOP these are tests for classes and methods. Unit tests are also isolated, so test a single unit in isolation from other units. Anything else is an integration test. Your test goes through the whole framework (routing etc), calls your controllers and other collaborators. It's definitely NOT a unit test.

Comment: That smiley face makes it much better :-D. OK bro, gotcha, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem. Apparently ( and I'm not sure yet, because the documentation doesn't state it at all ) you can't use the `attach` method when testing JSON APIs. So here's how I solved the problem. Instead of

```
    $this->post(route('share.upload'), ['type' => 'video'],
        ['HTTP_Authorization' => "Bearer " . $token])
        ->attach($this->test_case_files_path . 'testcase.mp4', 'file')
        ->seeJson(['error' => false]);
```

I used this:

```
$uploadedFile = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
            $file, 'testcase.mp4', 'video/mp4', filesize($file), null, true
        );
        $this->response = $this->call('post', route('share.upload'), ['type' => 'video'], [],
            ['file' => $uploadedFile],
            $this->transformHeadersToServerVars([
                'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $token,
                'Content-type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            ]));
        $this->seeJson(['error' => false]);
```